# Why does API return 404 when connecting through postman Kestrel environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-routing

I'm working on an Angular project with .net core api. in development environment. api enpoint returns 404 when connecting with postman

```
localhost:5000/api/OrderParts/ returns 404
```

controller

```
namespace Inventory.API.Controllers
{
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(LogUserActivity))]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OrderPartController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IOrderPartRepository _repo;


        public OrderPartController(IOrderPartRepository repo)
        {
            this._repo = repo;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrderParts([FromQuery]UserParams userParams)
        {
            var orderParts = await _repo.GetOrderParts(userParams);


            Response.AddPagination(orderParts.CurrentPage, orderParts.PageSize,
                orderParts.TotalCount, orderParts.TotalPages);

            return Ok(orderParts);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if https is enabled in your project, if it’s enabled then your url on postman needs have https:local host:5000/.......

Answer (score 2):

You called your controller `OrderPartController` so your API URL should be `/api/orderpart`. Take off the s at the end.